# Android interface : show form like the grouped listview style?

Tags: android, listview, interface

I'm building an App for Android that already exists for iOS. On iOS, we really like to use the [listview grouped style](http://www.mosync.com/files/images/ListView-widget-segmented-list-on-ios.img_assist_custom-220x329.png) to show details and forms. It is really useful to show details of objects that we don't know how much properties they have before loading it.

I know that Android doesn't have a similar tableview style. And I don't want to use a custom library to recreate it, because I don't want to force an iOS like interface to my Android's users.

But how would you create a consistent Android interface that show similar information? Do you have example for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your instinct to not force iOS style UI onto Android users is correct and I respect you for it.

Android's ListView is roughly the equivalent of iOS's UITableView. There are important differences. For instance, you should never use a ListView inside another scrollable container. If a ListView is in a particular layout, it should (usually) be the only scrollable component. If you want multiple ListViews in a layout, you probably don't want ListViews at all. You should instead use (vertical) LinearLayouts and add the items in order.

Cyril Mottier writes [excellent posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Cyril%20Mottier%22%20%22ListView%20Tips%20&%20Tricks%22&oq=%22Cyril%20Mottier%22%20%22ListView%20Tips%20&%20Tricks%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.12884&ie=UTF-8) on implementing custom behavior for Android's ListView.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your advice about not using a ListView in a layout with multiple list. This is what I was trying to do, and it doesn't work really well. I will try your way and give you some news about it!

Comment: I tried your solution, and it works really well! I recreated a ListView with a LinearLayout. But while doing this, I just realize that I was may be in the wrong direction. So I decided to change entirely my interface so it is now even more Android Friendly.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display data in a list then you can use the [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html). [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) is a great article about how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for the link, it is the tutorial I follow to create a listview that takes the entire screen. But my present question is actually a little bit more complicated that this.

Comment: @NLemay do you want your ListView to cover up the whole screen?

Comment: Not really. On iPhone, a single ListView could handle multiple sections with different header when it was set to "grouped style". I know I can add an header to a ListView in Android, but I didn't found a way to reproduce the "grouped style" of the iPhone. It needs to feel more like a form then a list.